# Unable to generate crumb cookie with Hapi/crumb

Tags: typescript, hapi

I've registered the crumb plugin like

```
register: {
  plugins: [
    {
       plugin: crumb,
       options: {
         restful: true,
         autoGenerate: true,
         cookieOptions: {
           isSecure: false
         }
       }
     }]
}
```

Then in the routes that I'd like to use the crumb in, I've found through the Github examples that I should be able to use it like

```
request.plugins.crumb.generate()
```

However, crumb doesn't have a method generate() when I try that...

if I log `request.plugins` I just see something like `{ crumb: random-token-here }`

I can try with `request.server.plugins.crumb.generate()` but then I can't suppress the Typescript errors: `Property 'crumb' does not exist on type 'PluginProperties'`

Need help getting it to work please.